# Accessing an object with a dynamic key

Tags: angular

I am trying to access an object key with dynamic name

I have an angular template that looks like this

```
<div *ngFor= "let item of dataagg">
</div>
```

Where dataagg is an array of objects .

```
dataagg = [ 
{
name: "abc",
age: 32
},
{
name: "xyz".
age: 22
}
];
```

Now i have another object which is indexed by the 'name' property of the dataagg as follows:

```
infodata = {
"abc" : {message:"hello"},
"xyz" : {message:"bye"}
}
```

Now i need to access the infodata object with the 'name' property of the dataagg in the angular template .

I have tried some thing like this:

```
<div *ngFor= "let item of dataagg">

<div>{{infodata[item.name].message}}</div>
</div>
```

But it throws me error saying cannot read property of undefined.

Please let me know where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because `infodata[item.name]` gives you null if infodata does not have a message from datatagg

You may try

```
<div *ngIf="infodata[item.name]">{{infodata[item.name].message}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a message function to return message, and call this function from the html side

like

```
    showMessage(name: sting)
    {
      if (infodata[name] != undefined)
        return infodata[name].message;
      return '';
    }
```

and in your HTML code like this.

```
<div>{{showMessage(item.name)}}</div>
```